# Create EMR Cluster and Terminate after running Python script from S3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, emr, boto3

Is it possible to use boto3 to create an emr cluster and read a python script in s3 and then terminate. I know this could be done with creating cluster and then manually copying the script from s3 to the master during bootstrap but wondering if there was a way to do it differently that wouldn't involve copying the file. In other words creating a cluster and adding a step where you read directly from s3.

Answer (score 0):

Using boto3, you can programmatically add a step to an EMR cluster using

> add_job_flow_steps

http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.add_job_flow_steps

Comment: But what if its not a jar file but rather a python script in s3? Is add_job_flow_step only for jar files?

Comment: Step can be written in Python, using the Streaming API.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/CLI_CreateStreaming.html